# python convert letter to telephone number

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a beginner to python programming this is my first semester taking programming.I am having a little trouble. we are working with strings so i am guessing i would have to convert everything to a string.So the goal of this problem is to convert a telephone number with words such as: 
1-800-flowers to 1-800-3569377 
I am not allowed to use lists or dictionaries, just variables and must include a WHILE LOOP. this is what i had so far:

```
print('format: X-XXX-XXXXXXX')

user_input = str(input("give me a phone number: "))

key_alph='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

key_num= '22233344455566677778889999'

total=''

while user_input[6:12].isalpha():

    if user_input[6:12] in key_alph:

        print(user_input[:6]  ,key_num)
```

any help would be much appreciated. 
if possible, could the answer not be revealed, but if oyuu have to in order to explain that would be fine. I do not know if i need to use the index function or the .append method....
thank you in advance
danny m

Comment: i pretty much want to say if user_input is in the variable key_alph, then whatever letter corresponds to key_alph, print out the key_num.

Comment: Instead of trying to process all characters at once, you need to do a character-by-character scan. Your while loop can be something like `while i < len(user_input)`.

Comment: Your whole while / if / print-thingy doesn't make any sense, [6:12] refers to a substring starting from position 6 to position 12, and doesn't change.

Comment: What's the problem with my answer? Enter the test data you gave and you'll see the right answer in plain sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user_input = (input("give me a phone number: "))

key_alph='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

key_num= '22233344455566677778889999'

counter = len(user_input[:6])

total=user_input[:6]    #Stores the part of string which is not going to be changed ("1-800-")

while (counter>0):
    alpha = user_input[-counter]
    if alpha.isalpha():   #checks if each character in the input is a valid alphabet and not a number.
        total+=key_num[key_alph.index(alpha)]  #Appending the new characters after the "1-800-" 
    else:
        total+=alpha     #This will preserve if any numeric character is encountered and keeps it same as in the input
    counter -= 1
print total
```

Comment: That depends on the user How to handle that case, But I handled that case in the else condition by simple keeping it same as it is.

Comment: Question clearly says that solution must include use of while loop.

Comment: thank you @ anmol_uppal for the answer. do you have a personal email address.

Comment: Yeah, it's mentioned in the bio I guess. @DanielMedina

Comment: @ anmol-uppal- what function is  "alpha = user_input[-counter]" where the [-counter] is. is that an index function? i understand alpha would be a new variable.  and also would you be able to explain in further detail what the total+=key_num[key_alph.index(alpha)] is... after the key_num... if that is an index function, i tried that before and it wouldnt let me because it would always say INT is not iterable.

Comment: @Anmol_uppal, sorry I do not use facebook, I stick mostly to GMAIL and LIVE.

Comment: anmoluppal365@gmail.com